# Django app using sitewide cache always sets Last-Modified header to now

Tags: python, django, caching, nginx

I'm experimenting running my Django app on a new server (nginx). I've configured Django's filesystem caching (see below for config). This is the full set of headers I get back for my URL:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.1.19
Date: Sun, 04 May 2014 19:40:56 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 14408
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Encoding: gzip
Expires: Thu, 15 May 2014 05:39:17 GMT
Vary: Cookie, Accept-Encoding
Last-Modified: Sun, 04 May 2014 19:39:17 GMT
Cache-Control: max-age=900000
Set-Cookie: csrftoken=qZJziTgGHyJEhSZ03xKwazR43tqodubE; expires=Sun,
    03-May-2015 19:39:17 GMT; Max-Age=31449600; Path=/
P3P: CP="ALL DSP COR PSAa PSDa OUR NOR ONL UNI COM NAV"
```

The `Last Modified` field is, as you can see, less than a minute before the `Date` of the request. This seems to happen consistently: each time I reload the page, it sets this field to the current time (or just before). This means my `90000` second timeout (10 days) seems to always be relative to the current date.

Does anything in this Django cache config look weird?

```
CACHES = {
    'default': {
       'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.filebased.FileBasedCache',
       'LOCATION': '/var/www/mydir/CACHE',
       'TIMEOUT': 900000
    }
}

# without this it defaults to 600, despite above setting
CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_SECONDS = 900000
```

These are my middleware classes:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'middleware.SmartUpdateCacheMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.gzip.GZipMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.cache.UpdateCacheMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.cache.FetchFromCacheMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware'
)
```

(I'm using [SmartUpdateCacheMiddleware](https://www.silviogutierrez.com/blog/fixing-site-wide-caching-django/) to fix cookie issues with caching)

Is there any reason this is happening, or is this actually expected behaviour?